How to Include Response Headers from a WebClient Call in a Streaming ServerResponse in Spring WebFlux
I'm working on a Spring WebFlux application where I need to stream file back to the front end. The data streaming part is working fine when using DataBuffer with a reactive WebClient call. However, I encounter an issue when trying to include response headers received from the WebClient in the final ServerResponse sent back to the client.
Here's the code snippet that successfully streams the data:
public Mono<ServerResponse> exportAsStreaming(
    ExportExpensesRequest body,
    ForwardableHttpHeaders requestHeaders) {
    Flux<DataBuffer> responseBodyFlux = webClient
        .post()
        .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/api/exports/file").build())
        .headers(ServerRequestUtility.transferHttpHeaders(requestHeaders))
        .bodyValue(body)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class);

    return ServerResponse.ok().body(BodyInserters.fromDataBuffers(responseBodyFlux));
}

I attempted to extend this functionality to include certain response headers in the ServerResponse, such as Content-Disposition. The following is my approach:
@Override
public Mono<ServerResponse> exportAsStreaming(
    ExportExpensesRequest body,
    ForwardableHttpHeaders requestHeaders) {
    AtomicReference<HttpHeaders> responseHeaders = new AtomicReference<>();
    Flux<DataBuffer> responseBodyFlux = webClient
        .post()
        .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/api/exports/file").build())
        .headers(ServerRequestUtility.transferHttpHeaders(requestHeaders))
        .bodyValue(body)
        .exchangeToFlux(clientResponse -> {
            // Attempt to access and map the headers from the client response
            responseHeaders.set(clientResponse.headers().asHttpHeaders());
            return clientResponse.bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class);
        });

    return ServerResponse.ok()
        .headers(httpHeaders -> {
            httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
            if (responseHeaders.get().containsKey(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION)) {
                httpHeaders.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, responseHeaders.get().get(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION).get(0));
            }
        }).body(BodyInserters.fromDataBuffers(responseBodyFlux));
}

However, the responseHeaders AtomicReference seems to be null at the time of setting the headers in ServerResponse. I understand this might be due to the asynchronous nature of the reactive stream, but I'm unsure how to correctly include the headers from the WebClient response into the ServerResponse.
Can anyone review my approach and provide suggestions for correctly including response headers in the ServerResponse?
